# Slang: What does テラス mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

What does テラス means in the context of declining an invitation, like below?

> うううううう！！いきたい！けどその時間帯もろに仕事だ：：：またやって！！テラスーーーーー

I guess it is slang?

I am familiar with テラワロス but it seems different in both spelling and context.

More context: Public comment sent on a night-time birthday event page on a social network. テラス is not her nickname.

Comment: Well, it is supposed to be a given name. There are even kanji for that one. The sentence itself is complete, the final テラス is something more. Japanese usually use to put their name at the and of the sentence. I think it is a given name!

Comment: Maybe there's some slang meaning of `照らす`?

Comment: About the テラワロス... The context does not really let this term being applied here! I don't see any reason (logic reason) why someone who cannot go to a place where he wants to go (but cannot because of his job) should start laughing until he rolls on the floor (while keeping on laughing...).

Comment: @istrasci: I found some examples, but using 照らす just to refer to: "golden days", "those nice days...". Really out of context...

Comment: @Nicolas: Please give us something more to think about :) We need context... I measn, ok, declining an invitation... but was it by text message? is it an email? is it a conversation?

Comment: @Andry: I added details and asked her too... It seems to be much more local than I expected.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: Wow!!! For real... looks like something really slang and localized to a particular area... Ok, guess I have nothing else left other than asking my Japanese friends... gimme some time, gonna come back with an answer (I hope...).

Comment: OK she replied and apparently she thought the event place was on a terrasse... sorry for wasting everyone's time! (-_-;) This question is probably besy deleted, if a moderator is around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far the only viable explanation I can think of is that テラス is a contracted form of テラワロス.

- [ニコニコ[百科]{ひゃっか} entry for テラス](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%83%86%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9) defines it as: `3. テラワロスの略`

  - 3rd sense: Contraction of "terawarosu"
- [a 2ch.net post](http://2chnull.info/r/train/1273323743/901-1000) says:`「法テラス」（ﾃﾗﾜﾛｽじゃないぞｗ）`

  - "Law-terrace" (and no, it's not "terawarosu" lol)
- [a blog post](http://blog.kanjosen.com/?eid=1006137) writes: `「針テラス（テラワロスではない。2ちゃんの見過ぎ）」`

  - "[Hari Tea-time Resort Station](http://hari-trs.com/haritrs.html) (to 2ch addicts: it's not "terawarosu")"

As to why you'd want to "roll on the floor laughing" in the context of declining an invitation, I don't have a definitive answer, but maybe one of these:

- She's laughing at the unexpected coincidence of the event and her work.
- She's laughing at herself for having to work when everyone else is able to attend the event. Perhaps the time of the event is normally considered overtime?
- She's softening the request to hold another event for her by adding a laugh.

Comment: I think you got it! The event is a birthday party, so the `またやって！！` is humourous, and テラス means テラワロス.

Comment: [As to why you'd want to "roll on the floor laughing" in the context of declining an invitation, I don't have a definitive answer] -- Why not, people use `LOL` in English for **everything** these days, even things that aren't funny at all.